# Is it better to develop swimming fitness first or get better at technique?

Tags: swimming

Some say; you have to get better at your swimming technique before swimming longer distances. But others (minority) suggest that you have to develop swimming fitness before worrying about technique? Which is the right way to start?

Comment: I am not a swimmer, but I am a firm believer in that technique comes first. In this case, how do you build "swimming fitness"? By swimming a lot, I suppose. Why wouldn't you try to swim better meanwhile? By actively bettering your technique all the time, you would spend a lot of time in the water, gaining fitness at the same time.

Comment: Some arguments for technique can be found in these posts, http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/429/3778 and http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/5171/3778

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to assume that you are coming from a mostly non competitive swimming background.

There has to be a baseline of both, but I lean towards the emphasis that you need to be a fitter swimmer before you can really start effectively working on your form. Even if you do 2000 yards/meters in increments of 50 (two lengths or one lap) working strictly on form, if you don't have the fitness to swim a 200m distance, as soon as your fitness fails, your form will soon follow.

Also, there is some evidence that gross flaws in your stroke will self correct as you get fitter, so that by the time you can swim a decent distance, some of your worst mistakes will have corrected themselves. Obviously, the fine points of the stroke won't magically fix themselves, but some of the bigger flaws will.

My recommendation would be to follow a program such as the [Ruth Kazez 0 - 1 mile](http://ruthkazez.com/ZeroTo1mile.html) program (6 weeks to swim 1 mile) to get a good baseline of fitness, then you can develop a program that will continue that fitness while you add in stroke refinement drills.

Good drills for stroke improvement:

- Catchup drill
- Fingertip Drag
- Fist Drill
- One Arm
- Sculling
- Side kicking

However, there can be a limit to how much you can improve your stroke on your own without feedback from an instructor. Not a coach, a coach is someone who can build a workout season, an instructor teaches strokes and refinements. They can be one and the same, but often are not. For other feedback, I also highly recommend the [SwimSmooth](http://www.swimsmooth.com/) program, which is a good online resource, and there are also a lot of technique videos on youTube that you can go through.

Comment: Good answer, the key is the baseline. What I have seen from myself and other beginners is that if the technique is below the baseline, only a few would finish the a program like the Kazez. On the other hand, all the beginners I have seen have been quite active in other sports, i.e. quite fit. So what is a way of finding out if you are above/below the "waterline" in terms of technique?

Comment: @FredrikD - Swim down and back normally. If it takes you more than ~30 per each length (so 60+ strokes total), then you might have some serious stroke work that needs to happen. A stroke is counted each time a hand enters the water. That would be about the only non visual (i.e. not an instructor looking at you) way I could think of to assess it. As an n=1 example, I take 14-17 strokes per length as a former swimmer, even when I'm out of shape, so 28-34 strokes per 50.

Answer (score 2):

I used to have this notion that I would get in better shape by swimming with suboptimal technique, and therefore get more resistance. My girlfriend at the time was a good swimmer and thought the idea was ridiculous. I later had a friend who was quite into swimming as well, and had to stop entirely due to some serious muscular dysfunction in his shoulder from thousands of reps of a technique that was just a bit off.

So even if you do somehow get better fitness by not worrying about technique, you're still prone to injury. Technique first is the only sensible way to go. You're not going to get in better shape if you're sidelined due to an overuse injury, and the people who are good at swimming seem to think you get the fitness from the technique.